# Configure git to accept only well formatted and documented push

Tags: git, formatting

At our office, one of the biggest problems of working with a team is to force them to use an standard way of documenting and formatting the code.

I was wondering, is there a way of configuring git (either github or a private git server) to allow ONLY the commits that has a certain documentation and code structure format? EG: All php functions must be documented with phpdoc, all the opening brackets must be in the same line of the function definitions, etc.

To summarize, can a git server be configured to parse some files before accepting a push to force users to format all the code according to a standard?

Comment: That would be a pre-commit hook -- but a complicated one at that.

Comment: Plus one for giving it a name! I didn't even know what to search for. I will search more information about those pre-commit hooks. Thanks!

Comment: It's great you found what you need. It's better if you add this as an answer to your question, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good approach to what I was looking for:

https://github.com/s0enke/git-hooks/tree/master/phpcs-pre-commit

It's based on executing PHP_CodeSniffer as a pre-commit hook. The git client will allow the commit only if the PHP_CodeSniffer tests are successful.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. One thing you'll want to keep in mind, though, is that clients will hang while the pre-commit hook is executed. If the tests take a long time to run, you may annoy your users while they wait for their code to commit. Of course, if they are only pushing into your repository occasionally, this might not be painful enough to matter.